# Azure Logic Apps FTP file content

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

I'm using Azure Logic Apps to copy files from FTP to Blob Storage. I'm using the action "FTP - When a file is added or modified" and after this I copy the file content to a Blob Storage.

The problem is that the file is being copied to Blob Storage before it is completely added to the FTP, and I get partial files.

Is there any way to hold Azure Logic Apps such that it will only copy the file after it is completed?

Comment: The workflow is a little hazy.  Can you redefine it?  You have a remote ftp, a trigger that polls that remote-ftp.  Are you (in your logic-app) taking that file and writing it to blob storage.  But the issue is that the trigger is being fired BEFORE the file is completely saved-off on the remote ftp site?  Thus is tries to pull a partial file?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And in my storage I see a partial file.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior happens when your FTP file system does not provide file locking. Similar behavior can occur when using the FTP-adapter in BizTalk.

In BizTalk, the best way to handle this is by modifying the client that is creating the file on FTP so that it uses temporary filenames.

- Client creates file ftpFile.tmp
- Client writes file content
- Client renames ftpFile.tmp to ftpFile.xml or whatever extension is needed
- BizTalk only picks up files with extension .xml

Major problem for me with the Logic Apps FTP connector is that you can't specify a file mask in the designer when using the connector as a trigger, which is strange, because i remember that option being available in the first version of logic apps.

Comment: Thanks. Since in my case, my customer uploads a file to their FTP everyday at 5AM, instead of having a Logic Apps trigger to put a message on a queue that is consumed by my WebJob, I'm going to trigger a WebJob at 6AM.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **Enable** the *Include File Content* Option.

You can do this in 2 ways.
1.
Go to *LogicAppDesigner*->Expand your *FTP-Trigger* ->Set **yes** to *Include File* Content

Like this

[image]

2. Go to *Logic App Code View*-> find the *Trigger* JSON- > Add **"includeFileContent": true** inside the **"Queries"**